# Angular Directive with dynamic attributes

Tags: angular

I need to render attributes on controls in Angular. The attributes will be configured based on a property. The user will send in a JSON file which will be serialized to an object in typescript. This typescript file will be used as the binding on the component.

```
{
      "row": 1,
      "col": 2,
      "key": "Input_2",
      "label": "First Name",
      "required": true,
      "type": 1,
      "hiddden": false,
      "maxLength": 100,
      "attributes": "required validateEqual='password' reverse='false'"
}


export class ControlBase<T> {
    row: number;
    col: number;
    value?: string;
    key: string;
    label: string;
    required: boolean;
    type: ControlType;
    hidden: boolean = false;
    attributes: string;
}

<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" {{control.attributes}}>
```

When I used the above binding {{control.attributes}} I get the following error : Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{control.attributes}}' is not a valid attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any template syntax that allows you to set a dynamic number of arguments. But it can be achieved with code
Here is a sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svcvsj

Check the input element with your browser's developer tools. The attributes should be there. I recommend  using a strongly typed object for the attributes to avoid doing the extra string parsing there

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thanks

Comment: Just one other thing. If for example one of the attributes is another directive. The directive doesnt seem to work. i.e. "attributes": "shownif required validateEqual='password' reverse='false'". Please see the sample: https://angular-ddqbzt.stackblitz.io. Thanks

Comment: you cannot add directives dynamically in Angular. It just doesn't work like that out of the box :). Attributes and directives are not the same things. Angular precompiles the templates at bootstrap or ahead of time and anything added afterward is just treated as regular attributes.